# jQuery Create Div with Elements

Tags: jquery

I used document.createElement to create a div with a class like this:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.className = 'note';
```

But i don't know how to get the div to have the html elements of .note and every time I trigger the block, it doubles however number of notes there are!  So if there were 4 notes, it would create 4 notes, resulting in 8 notes:( (.note is the div I'm copying)

here is the full code:

HTML:

```
<div class="note">
  <input id="subject" value="SUBJECT"></input>
  <div class="time"></div>
  <hr>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <input type="text" value="TYPE HERE"></input>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.note {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#FFFF19;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:1px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
input {
    background-color:#ffff19;
}
#subject {
    background-color:#ffff19;
    border:none;
    width:73px;
}
.time{
    height:25px;
    width:300px;
    float:right;
}

.note hr{
    width;350px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#wrp').click(function newNote() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = 'note'
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("wrp");
    $(newDiv).insertBefore('.note');
}
```

Comment: There is no element with id `wrp` in your code

Comment: I only added the code that went with that bit of js.  There is a div #wrp

Comment: Check this one: http://jsbin.com/lowukomugo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could simply **[`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** the `.note` element you want to copy.

```
$('#wrp').click(function() {
    var note = $('.note').first(); // assuming the first .note to clone
    note.clone().insertBefore(note);
});
```

Comment: It caches the first occurring `.note` on your DOM into a variable named `note`

Comment: And in the next step, it clones `note` and prepends to itself.

Comment: What does the browser console say? It should be straight forward to fix.

Comment: @ClayH Are you getting any error message in your console? Often when copy+pasting code it doesn't work immediately since things are different for each project. You need to understand the code and be able to debug it.

Comment: @DarkAshelin I'm not getting any errors in the console

Comment: @ClayH Have you been able to figure it out? Do you know how to debug?

Comment: @ClayH Generally, it's easiest to debug by putting `console.log()`s in your code. This will print out values to your console window, so you can check how far your code runs and where it goes wrong. In this case for example you could `console.log(note)` and see if it outputs what you expect (the `.note` element). Another way is by using [breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). With these methods you can almost always find out what exactly is wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm using jsfiddle, so console.log wont work...any other sugestio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) function to retrieve or replace the inner HTML (all the elements) of a div:

```
var noteHtml = $(".note").html(); //Retrieve all HTML / elements inside the .note div
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.className = 'note';
newDiv.html(noteHtml); //Place all the HTML / elements in the new div
```